# Do the capacity in modern hard disks get standardized?

Tags: hard-drive

It seems that the capacity of hard disks is standardized among manufacturers. I have 2TB drives x5 from 3 companies and they are of the same capacity.

- 2TB drive = 2000398934016 bytes

Can anyone confirm this or is there any exception? For example, 2TB != 2000398934016 bytes. This coincidence/convention makes replacement easier in RAID. :D

Note: This question is not related to the differences between decimal and binary  notations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disk capacities are indeed standardized for a while now courtesy of [LBA Count for Disk Drives Standard (LBA1-03)](http://idema.org/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=1223). This ensures all disks have the same LBA count and thus the same capacity.

You can use [online calculator](https://www.medo64.com/2017/06/watching-sector-count/#calculator) to determine what should be the sector count for desired capacity.